# Retrive key of type "bpy.data.objects[key]" from key of type "bpy.data.mesh[key]"

Tags: python, materials, data-blocks

Key Example: bpy.data.meshes[MaterialUser.name].

I'm obtaining mesh keys from bpy.data.materials and the data-blocks i get back includes a "Scene" datablock

if there is a way to retrieve the actual object key how could i got about it, from what i tested the only connection between mesh-data and the parent object it's their relative user

I'm aware of how to search the parent object of a mesh through it's users, but due to the fact it's already doing so for every scene materials the operator is already too expensive to be running a "clone" of the function used for materials, without running into performance issues on "material-dense" scene or even issues with the execution order due to what the operator does (which is irrelevant, and would complicate the question)

would there be a way to retrieve it that does not involve loops of every object in bpy.data.objects or any other expensive "file wide" searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [bpy.data.user_map](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.user_map). It outputs a dictionary with filtered keys and values. Keys are IDs and values are users of said IDs.

eg

```
import bpy

user_map = bpy.data.user_map(key_types={"MESH"}, value_types={"OBJECT"})
print(user_map)

# if you want to know all bpy.types.Object users of a mesh named "MyMesh" :

users_of_mesh = user_map.get(bpy.data.meshes["MyMesh"], None)
```

Note internally I'm sure it does loop at least once over every object and mesh, but I'm pretty sure this is the most concise and optimised way you'll get what you want. Unless you keep a dynamic list of meshes and users that you update with your own logic. But that's another can of worms.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking, i meant custom functions that do a file wide search, as i an internal function i believe would be more optimized, nice to know